# My Basil plant is not happy on my windowsill

Tags: houseplants, herbs

So recently, I bought a basil plant for a recipe. I placed it on my windowsill in the sunlight as expected. Watered it like instructed. It wilted.  So I moved it to my sink and now its thriving. I water it with luke warm water, not hot, just Luke warm, and its happy sitting in my sink. If I move it to the windowsill it has a tantrum and starts to wilt or turn yellow. Any ideas as to why my plant is being weird? Side note, I used to have a different house plant many years ago that also preferred the sink and lived for 3+ years but died as soon as I removed it from the sink. Any explanations for this oddity?

Comment: You can acclimate the basil slowly to more sun and average humidity.